# Preventing database attacks

Tags: php, database, arrays

Is it still relevant to use get_magic_quotes_gpc to prevent database attacks? I wanted to strip the extra slashes if magic quotes was enabled.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    If magic quotes is enabled, strip the extra slashes
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
}
```

I looked at the php manual and saw that it was deprecated. I am unsure of what alternatives I could use or if there may be a tweak I am unaware of. For I am still new to programming and learning different coding techniques. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should really be using parameterized queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: SO should just automate posts regarding use of PDO when it comes to php mysql_ questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
function mysql_prep($value)
{
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
    if ($new_enough_php) { 
        // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
        if ($magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else { 
        // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
        if (!$magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = addslashes($value);
        }
        // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return ($value);
}
```

I will suggest you to pdo `prepared statement`

```
$q=$pdo->prepare("query where id=:id");
$q->execute(array(":id"=>1))
```

Comment: No insult to jhonraymos.  But I'd upgrade PHP before ever using that code.  I know it ain't always a perfect world though.

Comment: How would you go about in upgrading it and why so? @ficuscr

Comment: Just saying.  PHP 4.3 was released in 2002.  I typically don't code around things that are not supported and over 10 years old.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks for the clarification @ficuscr